Window configured processors
Does Window leverages symmetrically configured processors to process threads from different memory spaces?
(Symmetric multiprocessing (SMP) refers to a system architecture in which multiple identical processors are connected to a single memory resource.)
I've tried chat GBTing it

Can you reframe as a computer programming question? Are you developing multiprocess solution and want to take advantage of all processors?
